# Extracting specific string in JAVA

Tags: java

I have data in a file as follows:

```
name: "Clooney, George", release: "2013", movie: "Gravity", imdb: "9",
name: "Pitt, Brad", release: "2004", movie: "Ocean's 12", imdb: "8",
name: "Clooney, George", release: "2004", movie: "Ocean's 12", imdb: "8",
name: "Pitt, Brad", release: "1999", movie: "Fight Club", imdb: "9",
```

I need to output it as follows:

```
name: "Clooney, George", movie: "Gravity",
name: "Clooney, George", movie: "Ocean's 12",
name: "Pitt, Brad", movie: "Ocean's 12",
name: "Pitt, Brad", movie: "Fight Club",
```

I'm pretty much new to Java. Can someone give me some hints and pointers on how to get this done?

Thanks,
TM

Comment: Post what you tried so far.

Comment: I'm even having difficulty to get this into a string in Java...i think because of the quotes and all...

Comment: The data is in a text file. I was able to read it into Java, but it seems to be giving some problems...will try to figure out with the links given in the answer and post back...

Comment: I think you can parse it easily with json library.

Comment: Comment to those who put this question as off-topic..I never asked for the code directly..I asked for some pointers in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String [] args){
        File file = new File("data.txt");

            Scanner scanner;
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(file);

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(line);

                    line = line.substring(7, line.length()-1);
                    String name = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\"")-1);

                    int index = line.indexOf("movie: \"");
                    line = line.substring(index+8, line.length()-1);
                    String movie = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\"")-1);

                    System.out.println("name: \"" + name + "\", movie: \"" + movie + "\",");
                }
                scanner.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, refer to the documentation of String:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

There, you might find a lot of useful methods to do any types of operations with Strings.

Algorithm to go:

a) split your string into smaller chunks

b) use the chunks

- hint: can    split with regex

As long as you always leave out release and imdb, you could also use replacement with empty line (""). It will be even easier.

Answer (score 1):

In the long-term, I would suggest you re-format what you have in the file, try to follow the JSON standard, then org.json library will be able to help you a lot. Otherwise, you will have some ugly and hard-coded lines to search, parse the String, which will be difficult to read and maintain in the future.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(\"name\": \"value\", \"release\": "\2013\", \"movie\": \"Gravity\", \"imdb\": \"9\");
```

**See also**: [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library

Answer (score 1):

Since this is very likely a learning exercise, here's a description of the approach that you can take:

- Start by writing a class `ActorMovie` that brings together the name of the actor and the name of the movie.
- Add a constructor or a factory function that parses a string, and gives you an `ActorMovie` object
- Create a list of `ActorMovie` objects
- Sort the list by actor name
- Print the list in the format that you want.

The `ActorMovie` class could look like this:

```
class ActorMovie {
    private String actorName;
    private String movieName;
    private int releaseYear;
    private int imdbRating;
    public ActorMovie(
        String actorName
    ,   String movieName
    ,   int releaseYear
    ,   int imdbRating) {
        this.actorName = actorName;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.imdbRating = imdbRating;
    }
    public String getActorName() {return actorName;}
    public String getMovieName() {return movieName;}
    public int getReleaseYear() {return releaseYear;}
    public int getImdbRating() {return imdbRating;}
    public static ActorMovie parse(String str) {
        ... // Add code to parse the string in the format that you specified
        return new ActorMovie(....);
    }
}
```

You have many options for parsing - you could use a regular expression to match the entire string, or walk the string character-by-character, avoiding commas that are enclosed in doublequotes.

For sorting a `List<ActorMovie>` objects use `Collections.sort` method:

```
List<ActorMovie> data = ... // Obtain a list
data.sort(data, new  Comparator<ActorMovie> {
    public compare(ActorMovie o1, ActorMovie o2) {
        return o1.getActorName().compareTo(o2.getActorName());
    }
});
```